# Replacing the price tag "0.00" with "Call"

Tags: php

am trying to replace my price tag which has a default price of "0.00" to "Call".They asked me to insert the code on the line of code below. The code below is the code in my functions.php page.

```
function get_listing_price(){ 
  if(get_field("price_layout","options") == "Right"){ 
    echo number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ',')." "; 
  } 
  echo the_field("currency_value","options"); 
  if(get_field("price_layout","options") != "Right"){ 
    echo " ".number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ','); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're missing and end curly bracket (`}`) /s.

Comment: function get_listing_price(){
 if(get_field("price_layout","options") == "Right"){
  echo number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ',')." ";
 }
 
 echo the_field("currency_value","options");
 
 if(get_field("price_layout","options") != "Right"){
  echo " ".number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ',');
 }
}

Comment: The code above is the whole code, what i want is a line of code that will make the default price tag "0.00" change to "call"

Answer (score 2):

*sigh* oh, alright then:

```
function get_listing_price() {

    if(!get_field("price")) { echo "Call"; }
    else {
        if(get_field("price_layout", "options") == "Right"){
          echo number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ',')." ";
        } 

        echo the_field("currency_value", "options"); 

        if(get_field("price_layout","options") != "Right") {
            echo " ".number_format(get_field("price"), 2, '.', ','); 
        }
    }
}
```

Although really SO shouldn't be about "do my job for me"...

Comment: But... but I thought the internet is where you get your job solved for free? Waahhh. :) +1 btw. :)